# FBFriendPickerViewController not scrolling to last cell: bug in Facebook SDK 3.2

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I am using FBFriendPickerViewController for displaying facebook friends.
In Facebook SDK 3.1 it is working fine, but recently I upgraded to Facebook SDK 3.2
Now you cannot scroll to the very last cell anymore, when having added a UISearchBar as subview of the canvas view

```
CGFloat searchBarHeight = 44.0;
FBsearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,
            self.view.bounds.size.width,
            searchBarHeight)];
FBsearchBar.autoresizingMask = FBsearchBar.autoresizingMask | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
FBsearchBar.delegate = self;
FBsearchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;

[self.canvasView addSubview:FBsearchBar];
CGRect newFrame = self.view.bounds;
newFrame.size.height -= searchBarHeight;
newFrame.origin.y = searchBarHeight;

self.tableView.frame = newFrame;
```

Does anyone have a solution to this? I upgraded to Facebook SDK 3.2 because the the FBWebDialogs are introduced for posting message on your own wall or your friends wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the trick to also be able to select the last entry:

newFrame.size.height -= 2*searchBarHeight;